# Calculus and Sin function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Find all the quatrains of points $ (x_1,f(x_1)),(x_2,f(x_2)),(x_3,f(x_3)),(x_4,f(x_4))$ on the graph of $f(x)=\sin x$ such that the tangents by the four points form a rectangle.

Could you help me to solve this out?

Comment: When sides are parallel to x-axis quadrilateral parallelograms are possible obviously but not rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need that

- $f'(x_i)\cdot f'(x_j)=-1\implies \cos x_i\cdot \cos x_j=-1\implies x_i=0\quad x_j =\pi$

thus we can choose

- $x_1=0$
- $x_2=\pi$
- $x_3=2\pi$
- $x_4=3\pi$

Comment: are there  another quatrain of point ?

Comment: @Henry since we need $\cos x_i\cdot \cos x_j=-1$ and $|\cos x|\le 1$ the first 4 points to obtain a rectagle are that. Of course there are infinitely many of those rectangles since $\sin x$ is periodic.

Comment: Ok, just one more question why $(cosx_i)cosx_j=-1$? how did you get to that?

Comment: @Henry Recall that for a tangent line $y=mx+n$ $m=f'(x)$ and the condition of orthogonality between two lines is $m_1\cdot m_2=-1$.

Comment: Ohhh thanks, mate really you helped me a lot!

Comment: @Henry You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Henry also recall that ou can accept the answer when they solved the OP, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: So if i want to get all the solutions it is true that $x_1=k2\pi$ $x_2=\pi + 2k\pi$ $ x_3=x_1+ 2k\pi$  $x_4=x_2+2k\pi$ ?

Comment: @Henry Ah ok you have to find them all. Then observe that always we obtain a rectangle choosing $x_1\neq x_3$ form $x_k=2k\pi$ and $x_2 \neq x_4$ form $x_k=\pi+2k\pi$.